# 2 buttons in a form, only one that performs form action

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to have 2 buttons in a form, and only one have them perform the form action (submit)?

**Edit:** My mistake guys. I'd been using button instead of input type="button". I wasn't aware that button always submitted, whereas input type="button" didn't. I simply assumed they both did, thus the lack of specification.

Thank you for those who answered not so rudely.

Comment: But both of my buttons perform the form action.

Comment: My mistake guys. I'd been using <button> instead of <input type="button">. I wasn't aware that <button> always submitted, whereas <input type="button"> didn't. I simply assumed they both did, thus the lack of specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make one a submit button and not the other.
Buttons that submit forms

- `<button></button>`
- `<input type=submit>`
- `<input type=image>`

Buttons that don't

- `<button type="button"></button>`
- `<input type="button">`

Comment: Thank you. My apologies for being non-specific.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, make one button with `type='button'`, not  `type='submit'`.

Comment: Ah. I had 2 <button>s. Not <input>s . Makes sense.